# My android app icon has a coloured background instead of transparent:

Tags: android, android-studio, transparent, imageicon

My android app icon is a **png** image with a **transparent background**. In the image asset configuration IN ANDROID STUDIO, I set its **shape** to be **NONE**. However still, whenever the app is installed on my device, a purple square background is present. However on another version of android, the app icon background is transparent. How do I remove it? Can somebody please shed some light?

Comment: Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling, clearing the app's cache, force-stopping it?

Comment: May be because of your phone Launcher setting it add  background to your app icon

Comment: Oh I've done that a million times.@Edric

Comment: Well, this problem isnt restricted to my phone alone. It has been seen in many other phones. @Anil

Comment: Have you tried installing it in stock android phone

Comment: Because I have seen background for glassdoor app icon in my phone.

Comment: @Anil What exactly is a stock android phone?

Comment: Like moto, pixel

Comment: A stock Android device is one which hasn't seen any modifications (rooting, custom launchers, custom icon packs or themes, ...).

Comment: It works fine with Pixel and Nexus. There have a transparent background. How to make it work on lower versions of android? @Anil

Comment: @ModularSynth Oh okay. Thank you! What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Maybe use custom styles/themes based on the OS Level.

Comment: As for as I know you can't do any thing with it

Comment: it's normal and it's not happen only with your app icon

Comment: Okay. Thank You! @Anil

Comment: Thanks @ModularSynth